# Office 365 create draft reply message rest API

Tags: office365

For Office 365 create draft reply message rest API '/messages/{message_id}/createreply' the required request body parameter is 'comment' as per the Office 365 documentation.

[Office 365 create draft reply message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#CreateReplyDraft)

I tried to create a draft reply using 'POST /messages/{message_id}/createreply' API with payload as:

{
  "Comment": "Fanny, Randi, would you name the group if the project is approved, please?" 
}

The API gives following error:

{
  "error": {
    "code": "RequestBodyRead",
    "message": "The parameter 'Comment' in the request payload is not a valid parameter for the operation 'CreateReply'."
  }
}

Is there anything wrong I'm doing or this is a known issue with Office 365 create draft reply API?

Comment: Can you try with the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer#/). I just tried this myself, and it looked to be working without error. Could you also share your code?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I did: http://imgur.com/a/uvWAk

Comment: Yes with Microsoft Graph it works fine. But I'm working on an integration connector which consumes Office 365 rest APIs. So I need to perform this task using Office 365 REST API only.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is any issues with the create draft reply API.
I was able to test this API call using a Native Client I registered in my tenant (with mail.readwrite scope registered), and a PowerShell script using ADAL which did Authentication and the REST call.

Here is that script:

```
Add-Type -Path "..\ADAL\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll";

$output = ".\Output.txt"
$accessToken = ".\Token.txt"

$clientId = "<AppID>";
$tenantId = "<Tenant or Common>";
$resourceId = "https://outlook.office.com"
$redirectUri = new-object System.Uri("<Reply URL>")
$login = "https://login.microsoftonline.com"

$authContext = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext @(("{0}/{1}" -f $login,$tenantId), $false);

$authenticationResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceId,$clientID,$redirectUri);

($token = $authenticationResult.AccessToken) | Out-File $accessToken


$headers = @{ 
    "Authorization" = ("Bearer {0}" -f $token);
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
}

$body = @{
    Comment= 'This is my comment'
}

$bodyJSON = $body | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri ("{0}/api/beta/me/messages/<message id>/createreply" -f $resourceId) -Headers $headers -Body $bodyJSON -OutFile $output
```

I was able to get a valid response from the API with this code. I am a little hesitant to share my output, I do not really know what is sensitive and what isn't, but I believe the error comes from the way your code is formulating your POST request. Can you share your code?

I hope this helps!